# IE6 min-height dilemma

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-6, css

Here is my site:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/ppp/home-page.html

I want the input forms to be the same height as the buttons to their right. I've done this with a min-height value so the page would still be usable if the text size was set to greater than this height.

The problem is that IE6 doesn't recognize min-height. I could set a fixed height, but I'm worried about users resizing the text beyond this. As it's only a cosmetic issue, I'm tempted just to leave this.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: uhm, still supporting IE6, with microsoft telling us to please stop using IE6 (http://www.theie6countdown.com/)

Comment: still being used though: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: _Don't_ support IE6, it should die!

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - Damn right! When people ask me what to do for IE6 users, I refer them to the wisdom of [Captain Jame Tiberius Kirk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Swvf3w6hcY4).

Comment: @jdln - 3.5% is pretty low, but those stats are worldwide. It's better to narrow it down to your site's actual user-base. See http://gs.statcounter.com for stats you can break down by region and country: In the US, UK and other western countries, IE6 usage is below 2% and falling every month. In places like Germany it's below 1%. It's much higher in places like China which is why the worldwide usage is still over 3%. But please take *all* stats with a pinch of salt - you need to play to your own site's demographics, not someone else's stats, so use your server logs to make the final decision.

Comment: Apparently none of you have a significant other working at a large institution whose employees are stuck with IE6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the issue is indeed just getting `min-height` working in IE6, use the [**Min-Height Fast Hack**](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/):

```
selector {
    min-height:500px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:500px;
}
```

It's been around for a long time, so it's easily recognizable for anybody maintaining your CSS in the future.

Comment: http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: Ive checked it again and yes, it seems to be working. Not sure what I did the first time. Thanks

Comment: Note the order of these lines has its importance and should not be altered.

Answer (score 3):

In Internet Explorer 6, `height` is treated as `min-height` and `min-height` is not supported.

So you can write a rule which targets only IE6 to fix this. Let's say that you have the following:

```
#navigation .nav-menu-item {
    min-height:50px;
}
```

In order to have the same effect in IE6 you could add a second rule which only IE6 will recognize. I tend to use [the star HTML hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_HTML_hack):

```
#navigation .nav-menu-item {
    min-height:50px;
}
* html #navigation .nav-menu-item { /* for IE6 */
    height:50px;
}
```

You can read more [here](http://www.search-this.com/2007/02/05/css-min-height-explained/).

Comment: +1 because it works, but I think you meant `height` in that last rule.

Comment: When I applied thirtydot's solution to the form, for testing I set the height and min-height to be 1px. From your posts I would have thought that the form should have stayed at its original height which is greater than 1px, however it actually shrunk to 1 px.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to offer a different approach. This is your goal, as stated:

> I want the input forms to be the same
>   height as the buttons to their right.

Plus, there is a condition of allowing for text resizing, as stated:

> still be usable if the text size was
>   set to greater than this height

Knowing that, my suggestion is to base the height on EMs. Use EMs to define the container height of the input and the button, then set the heights of the input and button to be 100%. This way, as the user resets their font size (from smallest to largest), the container will grow and shrink, and the input / button will grow and shrink with them.

I've mocked up a simple example at the following url: http://jsbin.com/oguze5/2/edit

Things will need to be changed for styling purposes, but the general idea / concept is pretty sound.

Comment: I like your solution but my 'Go' button is an image so I guess this wouldn't work me me. Thanks

Comment: You could set the image as the background image to the button element.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your post thirtydot. Ive seen that solution around but it didnt work for me, it set a fixed height non a minimum one.

Ive done it with the solution below and loaded the CSS for IE6 only for good measure. It works on the computer ive tested it on, I just hope it works for all IE6 computers:

http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/

Thanks

Comment: That's not as good as my suggestion. It relies on `expression`, which [degrades performance](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#AvoidCSSExpressions) (admittedly only a tiny amount in this case). It also won't work when JavaScript is disabled, whereas mine will. If my suggestion didn't work for you, you're probably using it wrong - it does work.

Comment: `expression` is the work of the devil! Seriously though, if first you're aiming to support IE6 and now you're beginning to use `expression` your skillset has begun to go backwards.